# Calling the right overloaded parent method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have a question regarding method overloading and inheritance. I
have the following program:

```
class Face {};
class Point {};

typedef double Real;

class Func
{
private:
  const char *m_name, *m_desc;

public:
  Func(const char *name,
       const char *desc) : m_name(name), m_desc(desc) {}

  virtual Real value(Face &f) = 0;

  Real value(Point &p) {return 0.;}

  virtual ~Func() {}
};


class QuadFunc : public Func
{
public:
  QuadFunc() : Func("quad", "Quadratic") {}

  Real value(Face &f) override {return 0.;}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QuadFunc func;

  Face f;
  Point p;

  func.value(f);
  // why doesn't this work?
  func.value(p);

  return 0;
}
```

Sadly g++ tells me that there is "no matching function for call to ‘QuadFunc::value(Point&)’". As far as I am concerned if I call
QuadFunc::value(Point&) the call should be redirected to the parent class Func.
This does work if I rename value(Point &p) to p_value(Point &p) and call that method instead. Can I somehow get the overloaded method to work as I expect?

Comment: Look-up "C++ name hiding". Shortcut : write `using Func::value;` in `QuadFunc`.

Comment: Have deleted my answer... you're right it wouldn't have helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your override in `QuadFunc` *hides* the overloaded function in `Func`.

You can bypass this hiding, by using a `Func` reference (or pointer) to a `QuadFunc` object:

```
QuadFunc qf;
Func &func = qf;

Face f;
Point p;

func.value(f);
func.value(p);  // Works
```

---

A better solution is to "import" the `value` symbol into the `QuadFunc` class from the `Func` class. You do that with the `using` keyword:

```
class QuadFunc : public Func
{
public:
    using Func::value;

    // ...
};
```

Then you don't have to use the reference workaround.

Comment: You can do that in C++03 too.

Comment: Thank you, I actually found an article about name hiding: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/c-name-hiding/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `using` directive if you want to overload a member function from a base class (also you might need the already mentioned `virtual`), so the code will become:

```
class QuadFunc : public Func
{
public:
  QuadFunc() : Func("quad", "Quadratic") {}

  using Func::value; //this is what you need
  Real value(Face &f) override {return 0.;}
};
```

Comment: Why did you removed the accepted answer form @Joachim Pileborg 's answer? i'm happy to receive reputation, but his answer is giving more information so i think your first accepted answer choice was better...

Answer (score 0):

The virtual function is hiding the function value(Point&), if you are explicit to the compiler as in:

```
  func.Func::value(p);
```

it does work! Test it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=77e3322e2a8d83e0f2d7990a2a0639ce-105ac1d5bf768d76df90c5569141bd7f).

In alternative you can just add

```
using Func::value;
```

into the QuadFunc declaration, as suggested by another answer.